# Is there a better code than waiting for JOGL display method to finish something?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, game-engine, jogl

I gotta tell you I didn't come up with a good title for the question, but I'll explain my situation.

I'm making a simple game in Java using OpenGL (JOGL). There is a key listener waiting for the left key to be pressed, and his happens when you press on the left key:

```
case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
     if (inControl) {
        inControl = false;
        alpha = 0;
        moving = true;
      }
```

As you can see, `inControl` decides if the player is able to make a move. Now by setting `moving` to false, I'm "sending a signal" to the `display` method, which contains the following code segment:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
   .
   .
   .
   if (moving) {
       .
       .
       .
       // Set color's alpha to alpha
       // Draw contents
       .
       .
       .
       if (alpha < 1.0f)
          alpha += 0.01f;

       if (alpha >= 1.0f) {
           inControl = true;
           moving = false;
       }
   }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

This means once I click left, somethings will gradually increase opacity until `alpha >= 1.0f`. The player must wait then, and this is done by putting `inControl = true` at the end of display method.

Although this works, I'm not a fan at all of this approach. Shouldn't the display method be exclusive to only displaying graphics, and not manipulate data?

Comment: You reply to your own question at the end. You shouldn't modify your data model in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable), this method should update the view, i.e the representation(s) of your model. I advise you to look at the existing 3D engines relying on JOGL to understand how we (... mainly I) solve this problem. If you really want to keep your code simple, you should at least separate the management of the model from the update of the view(s), for example by moving the former into a separate method even though you call it in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable) as a first step.

Comment: The "repaint on demand" idiom doesn't fit well into gaming. Rather always draw and enable vertical synchronization. You can put key and mouse events into a queue, read the content of this queue to update your data model elsewhere and read the model to update the view in GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable).

Comment: My question was what is a good example to avoid this. At the end what I did was do the translation calculations and then call the display method each time I change it. In the display, objects always translates by the 2 variables I manipulate in the key listener.

Comment: Your solution is viable as long as all changes occur in the key listener and are the consequences of player's actions but it doesn't make sense when there are changes caused by the artificial intelligence because it can occur when the player doesn't press any key, even in a simple game like Pong. Think about collision tests too. At the end, you'll probably retain only the information about the events in the listeners instead of doing the changes in the model inside them. I advise you to look at this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/ModeleMVC.png/370px-ModeleMVC.png

Comment: The step "warns of a change" in the schema above matches with what you do when you call GLAutoDrawable.display(). If you really want to decide when the redraw happens, you shouldn't use a build-in animator and then, you can create your own animator or simply use the typical gaming loop "while (running) {update(); render();}" in which render() just calls GLAutoDrawable.display() and update() calls your controller responsible for updating the data model (the translations in your case).